# How to make an array element appear on by one after the button is pressed in React JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onclick

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(["bmw", "mercedes", "audi"]);
  let result;
  let i = 0;
  function Add() {
  ????  
    
  }
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={Add}>Add item</button>
      <div>{arr.map(x => <p>{x}</p>)}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
  
  
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

This code above just prints all the array elements at once. How do I make 'em appear one by one after clicking the button (one click - arr[0] is displayed, second click - arr[1] is displayed etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new state to update the index, and have the button call that function. Then call another function that slices off the array elements up to the index, `map` over that array and return some JSX.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

 const [arr, setArr] = useState(['bmw', 'mercedes', 'audi']);

 // Add a new state for the index
 const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  // Click the button - update the index
  function addElement(arr) {
    setIndex(index + 1);
  }

  // Return some JSX by slicing the array up
  // to the index, and then `map` over that array
  // and return some divs
  function getElements(arr, index) {
    return arr.slice(0, index).map(el => {
      return <div>{el}</div>;
    });
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addElement}>Add item</button>
      {getElements(arr, index)}
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a state that represents`index` and the `slice` method:

```js
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

return (
<button onClick={() => setIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1)}>Click Me</button>
{array.slice(0, index).map(x => <p>{x} </p>)}
);
```

Comment: I've tried tweaking the 'index' variable but I would never have guessed to use slice! Thanks a lot!